# Bash: mailx attachment not recognised

Tags: linux, bash, mailx

I send emails using mailx, which works fine. When I am sending email with an attachment, on Gmail webui the attachments is OK, but not in Mail.app on Mac OS X.  The bash code:

```
( uuencode file file ) | mailx -s "subject" "asdf@gmail.com"
```

In Mail.app attachment show up as text in the body of message:

```
begin 777 file M[[N_(PT*(R!C8V-A;2!
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Don't use uuencode; it was never a good tool for the job it was supposed to do because its data format includes significant trailing blanks - and the permissions that uuencode/uudecode set on the decoded files are usually wrong.  Use a Base-64 encoding scheme.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be broken in Snow Leopard release, see [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314183709/http://www.macosxguru.net/article.php?story=20090916094622674) for a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I seen this article before -thanks-, but I want to use sendmail only  as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mailx -s "SUBJECT" -a FILE ADDRESS@SAMPLE.COM
```